# SSD dosn´t get detected by UEFI

Tags: ssd, bios, uefi

I installed a Samsung SSD in my computer, but it doesn´t get detected by UEFI, and because of that it cant boot.
But it´s detected by BIOS, so i can boot the system through BIOS.

Any ideas why it doesn´t get detected? And what to do about it?

(the boot order is unchangeable, UEFI always goes first)

(Im using Windows 10 and it´s a MSI 2AE0/Jasmine motherboard)

(The previous HDD is still installed and has GPT)

Comment: We need more information.  For instance what operating were you using?  Was this operating system installed on a HDD with GPT or MBR partitions?  Do not comment, just update your question, and include this vital information

Comment: Perhaps changing boot mode in BIOS from IDE to AHCI if it already is not on AHCI.

Comment: I assume the SSD is just unallocated space?

Comment: im using the OS on the SSD right now and it´s work perfectly, it´s just in the start up process i have to access bios to boot

Comment: If that is the case then the SSD is using MBR not GPT.